# File.Replace throws ERROR_UNABLE_TO_MOVE_REPLACEMENT

Tags: c#, io, filesystems

I have a 'safe' config file saving routine that tries to be atomic when writing user config data to the disk, avoiding disk caching etc.

The code goes something like this:

```
public static void WriteAllTextSafe(string path, string contents)
{
    // generate a temp filename
    var tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();

    // create the backup name
    var backup = path + ".backup";


    // delete any existing backups
    if (File.Exists(backup))
        File.Delete(backup);

    // get the bytes
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contents);

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        // write the data to a temp file
        using (var tempFile = File.Create(tempPath, 4096, FileOptions.WriteThrough))
            tempFile.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        // replace the contents
        File.Replace(tempPath, path, backup, );
    }
    else
    {
        // if the file doesn't exist we can't replace so just write it
        using (var tempFile = File.Create(path, 4096, FileOptions.WriteThrough))
            tempFile.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

On most systems this works perfectly and I have not had any reports of issues, but for some users each time my program calls this function they get the following error:

```
System.IO.IOException: 置換するファイルを置換されるファイルに移動できません。置換されるファイルの名前は、元のままです。
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.IO.File.InternalReplace(String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName, String destinationBackupFileName, Boolean ignoreMetadataErrors)
    at download.ninja.BO.FileExtensions.WriteAllTextSafe(String path, String contents)
    at download.ninja.BO.FileExtensions.SaveConfig(String path, Object toSave)
```

After a bit of investigation and with the help of Google Translate I've found that the actual error is thrown from the **wine32 ReplaceFile** function:

```
ERROR_UNABLE_TO_MOVE_REPLACEMENT 1176 (0x498)
The replacement file could not be renamed. If lpBackupFileName was specified, the replaced and
replacement files retain their original file names. Otherwise, the replaced file no longer exists 
and the replacement file exists under its original name.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365512(v=vs.85).aspx

The problem is that I have no idea why Windows is throwing this error.. I have tried setting the file to readonly locally but that throws an Unauthorized exception rather than a IOException so I don't believe that is causing the problem.

My second guess is that the the is somehow locked, but I only have one read function that is used for reading all config files and that *should* be closing off all file handles when it finsihes

```
public static T LoadJson<T>(string path)
{
    try
    {
        // load the values from the file
        using (var r = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);

            if (result == null)
                return default(T);

            return result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

I have also tried throwing fake exceptions in the LoadJson function to try and lock the file but I can't seem to do it.

Even then I have tried simulating a file lock by opening the file in a different process and running the save code while it is still open, and that generates a different (expected) error:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.IO.File.InternalReplace(String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName, String destinationBackupFileName, Boolean ignoreMetadataErrors)
    at download.ninja.BO.FileExtensions.WriteAllTextSafe(String path, String contents)
```

**So the question is.. what is causing Windows to throw this ERROR_UNABLE_TO_MOVE_REPLACEMENT error on some systems**

**NOTE**: This error is thrown **EVERY TIME** my program attempt to replace the file on an affected machine.. not just occasionally.

Comment: Does `File.Move(tempPath, path);` work?

Comment: I don't know, I am adding an exception handler to trap the IOException now so that it tries to File.Delete(path) then File.Move(tempPath,path) in that case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, so found the problem. It seems that files passed into ReplaceFile must be on the **SAME DRIVE**

In this case the user had changed their temp folder to d:\tmp\

So File.Replace looked something like this:

```
File.Replace(@"D:\tmp\sometempfile", @"c:\AppData\DN\app-config", @"c:\AppData\DN\app-config.backup");
```

This difference in drives between the source file and the desitnation file in `File.Replace` seems to be what caused the problem.

I have modified my `WriteAllTextSafe` function as follows and my user reports the problem has been resolved!

```
public static void WriteAllTextSafe(string path, string contents)
{
    // DISABLED: User temp folder might be on different drive
    // var tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();

    // use the same folder so that they are always on the same drive!
    var tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

    ....
}
```

As far as I can find there is no documentation stating that the two files need to be on the same drive but I can reproduce the problem by manually entering different drives (yet valid paths) into `File.Replace`

Comment: [`ReplaceFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs state “the backup file, replaced file, and replacement file must all reside on the same volume.” .net uses this to implement `File.Replace()`. Since this operation is analogous to POSIX [`rename()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html) which has `EXDEV`, it can be expected to have the same limitations. Supporting this operation across filesystem volumes would require solving the “distributed transactions” problem between distinct filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance, hardcoding drives in your file name, e.g. c:\ etc?

If you are, don't, they might not not work in runtimes where the locale is 1041 (japanese).

Instead use the framework to get the drive part and dynamically build your path.

```
string drivePath = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(System.Environment.SystemDirectory);
string somePath = string.Concat(drivePath, "someFolder\SomeFileName.Txt");
```

Comment: Interesting theory.. the path is not hard wired but generated using Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData, I don't think that should cause the problem suggested in your answer? essentially (in one line): `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "DownloadNinja", "app-config");`

Comment: I forgot to mention, the final file as listed in the user's log is `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\DownloadNinja\app-config` so that all looks OK as far as I can tell

Comment: Can you confirm that the path actually exists on the users machine like that.  C:\ could be wrong and it could have invalid environment variables which would cause Environment.SpecialFolder to come back with the wrong drive info.

If the drive in the path is wrong the File.Create will error out probably since File.Exists will be false.  You could use GetPathRoot to get the drive from the path "c:\" then user Directory.Exists to see if "c:\" exists as a second layer of exception handling on top of File.Exists.

Comment: OK found the problem, turns out the user had his tmp folder configured on his d:\ and apparently `ReplaceFile` doesn't work if the two files are on different physical drives :( thanks to MS for documenting this!

Comment: Even if the special folders appear differently named in Explorer, they’re actually named the same on the FS.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem working with source files on OneDrive copying to local files under %AppData%. A solution that worked well for me was to delete the destination file then perform a copy from the source.

Code that does **not** work:

```
file.replace(source,destination,backup,false)
```

Code that does work:

```
File.Delete(destination)
File.Copy(source, destination)
```

Comment: This defeats the whole purpose of transactional file replacement (unless you’re using this within a bigger meta pattern to provide transactional behavior). For move people who edit a randomly named new file and then use `File.Replace()` to replace an original file, this is not helpful.